# Install button greyed out on play.google.com

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I tried installing an app on my phone from the Play Store website, but the install button is greyed out. What could be the problem?

The phone is a Samsung Epic 4G running 4.0

Comment: Just tested. The install button is only greyed out if your device is incompatible. To test this from the device dropdown hover over the phone. It should say that `This item is not compatible with your device`.

Comment: What could be the prob..?Does samsumg epic 4g has something that app doesn't support?

Comment: App compatibility is a complicated issue. It depends on what the app developer made it available for. Could be that the app is not ICS ready, could be your carrier or just the phases of the moon.

Comment: It works on ICS but not samsung epic 4g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The install button is greyed out if you have no compatible device linked to your Google account.

[image: Play store screenshot]

Comment: I am getting this issue and my phone is compatible. It seems there is some other reasons...

Comment: @Loenix, check if you are logged into the same account which is linked to your phone.

Comment: @Aayush This is the same account.

Answer (score 88):

It is possible that you searched for the app using google. Somehow the google result links to the US version of the page, which grays out the install link for non-US people.

Remove the "gl=US" at the end of the URL address.

Comment: When using google to search for a App, it will append `&gl=US` to the link, as you are not from the US, the button will be grayed out. By removing ( or simply chaning the US to your country, eg for me Austria = &gl=AT ) it works again.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the button was greyed out when I accessed the google play store by using a web search for an app and then following the link to the play store.

If I went to the play store first and then searched for the app, there was no problem.

The solution proposed by Georgi121270 (remove the "gl=US" at the end of the URL address) solved the problem. It seems that the web search found the US version of the play store, whereas when I went directly to the play store, it took me to the version for my local region.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it says the app is compatible with all my devices, but the reason seems to be that the app is not available in my region (this is not mentioned anywhere).

Comment: ah, that's probably my situation -- being in Canadia.