# "This app is compatible with all your devices", but the Install button is greyed out on the web version of the Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

On the web version of the Play Store, the "Install" button is greyed out even though the message says: "This app is compatible with all of your devices."

[image: screenshot of the webpage]

What is the possible reason, and how to fix this?

Comment: this happens to me all the time with some apps. The app is available if I use the play store app in the phone though.

Comment: I had the same issue. I think it is a google bug (or an unexpected feature effectively working as a bug). However, I still could install anything I wanted to, only not from the web.

Answer (score 8):

Just saw this workaround posted by a Stefan Brunnauer on Google Play Help, and it worked perfectly for me

"Had the same problem - I removed the missmatching &gl=US query parameter at the end of the browser URL and it worked. Maybe this helps."

Comment: Still valid at 06/2022

Comment: Still valid in 02/2024!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that even if the app is compatible, it might be blocked in your country.

As mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231498/344378), removing the country parameter on your url will help.

For example, if the URL is
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dubox.drive&hl=en_AU&gl=US`

removing the `&gl=US` like so:
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dubox.drive&hl=en_AU`

This solved the problem for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used an incognito window to sign in and it worked. So maybe something to do with browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the greyed install application on Android emulator :

1. Choose an emulator configured with Google Apis **AND Google Play Store**.
2. Launch the Play Store application to install your desired application.
   With these settings I can install my chosen apps.
   *Hope this will aid someone!*

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site focusing on issues faced by end-users and power users. Just want to note that the question is specifically talking about the web Play Store, not the app version.